Cannot find "syscall_32.tbl" even though kernel source is installed
OS:
lsb_release: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
uname -r: 5.15.0-97-generic
I have a camera connected to a USB network adapter via an Ethernet cable, which in turn is connected to a Linux machine via USB.
I'm trying to install linux usb network adapter. I uploaded the files here too. When you download and unzip there is one source file. The readme just says to run make command.

When I run make I get the errors below. Even if I do sudo make although I don't get Permission denied errors, I still get No rule to make target ...syscall_32.tbl error. I tried sudo apt-get install linux-source and it installed the source, but syscall_32.tbl is still missing. I'm lost what should I even try?
user@user-Latitude-9410:~/Downloads/USB_Adapter$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-97-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625049’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625051’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625053’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625056’: Permission denied
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625077’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625079’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625081’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_625119’: Permission denied
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:217: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2

UPDATE
I tried building with make M=$PWD as recommended by @steeldriver and now it seems fixed the No rule to make target..., but now I get compilation errors. It seems it indeed uses old code. Any ideas what should I give to make to resolve this?
user@user-Latitude-9410:~/Downloads/USB_Adapter$ make M=$PWD
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-97-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.o
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c: In function ‘ax88179_get_settings’:
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:688:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  688 |  return mii_ethtool_gset(&dev->mii, cmd);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c: At top level:
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:816:3: error: ‘struct ethtool_ops’ has no member named ‘get_settings’; did you mean ‘get_strings’?
  816 |  .get_settings  = ax88179_get_settings,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   get_strings
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:816:19: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_eeprom *, u8 *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_eeprom *, unsigned char *)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_cmd *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  816 |  .get_settings  = ax88179_get_settings,
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:816:19: note: (near initialization for ‘ax88179_ethtool_ops.set_eeprom’)
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:817:3: error: ‘struct ethtool_ops’ has no member named ‘set_settings’; did you mean ‘get_strings’?
  817 |  .set_settings  = ax88179_set_settings,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   get_strings
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:817:19: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_coalesce *, struct kernel_ethtool_coalesce *, struct netlink_ext_ack *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_cmd *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  817 |  .set_settings  = ax88179_set_settings,
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:817:19: note: (near initialization for ‘ax88179_ethtool_ops.get_coalesce’)
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c: In function ‘ax88179_get_settings’:
/home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.c:689:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
  689 | }
      | ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter/ax88179_178a.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1911: /home/user/Downloads/USB_Adapter] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2
user@user-Latitude-9410:~/Downloads/USB_Adapter$ 


A Google search tells me this is a very old 32 bit piece of code. It is not clear what you are doing but I suspect it can not be done with the unnamed version of Ubuntu you are using. Maybe you can edit the question and add some more detail.

@David, I added what I'm trying to do (get access to a camera via usb adapter) and the version of Ubuntu

FWIW I don't recommend using sudo to brute-force permissions like this - you should probably have run make M=$PWD instead, or used the KBUILD_EXTMOD environment variable

@steeldriver make M=$PWD indeed helped, but now I get compilation errors. Probably I should pass something to make. I updated my post. Any ideas or should I now post a question in stackoverflow since it's related to code now?

Well like @David said, it's old code (ancient by kernel standards) so it may not even be possible to build it for a current kernel. Are you sure it is necessary? Have you checked to see if there's already a suitable module e.g. ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax* ?
